# Setting download directory in webdriver using JS

Tags: javascript, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

I want to change default download directory for chrome using JS (TypeScript). Tryed to set options like this :

let options = webdriver.ChromeOptions;

options.add_argument("download.default_directory=C:/Downloads")

let driver = webdriver.chrome(options);

But, options sets to undefined and ChromeOptions doesn't exist on webdriver.

Here is full code:

```
let webdriver = require('selenium-webdriver');
let chrome = require('selenium-webdriver/chrome');
let chromedriver = require('chromedriver');

chrome.setDefaultService(new chrome.ServiceBuilder(chromedriver.path).build());

// let driver = new webdriver.Builder()
//     .withCapabilities(webdriver.Capabilities.chrome())
//     .build();
let options = webdriver.ChromeOptions;

options.add_argument("download.default_directory=C:/Downloads")

let driver = webdriver.chrome(options);

let figma = 'https://www.figma.com/';
driver.get (figma).then(
    backup
);

function backup() {
    driver.sleep(3000);
    driver.quit();
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to [this](https://github.com/SeleniumHQ/selenium/issues/5292) issue, *chromeOptions* key doesn't work as intended. Use *goog:chromeOptions* to set options for chrome capabilities:

```js
const chromeCapabilities = webdriver.Capabilities.chrome();

chromeCapabilities.set('goog:chromeOptions', {
    'args': ['disable-infobars'],
    'prefs': {
      'download': {
        'default_directory': '/home/{user}/Downloads/Chrome_test',
        'prompt_for_download': 'false'
      }
    }
});

const driver = new webdriver.Builder()
  .withCapabilities(chromeCapabilities)
  .build();
```

Answer (score 0):

Try below code and let me know:

```
var chrome = require('chromedriver');
var chromeCapabilities = webdriver.Capabilities.chrome();
const chromeOption = require('selenium-webdriver/chrome');
//setting chrome options to start the browser fully maximized
var chromeOptions = {
    'args': ['--test-type', '--start-maximized'],
    'prefs': {"download.default_directory":"/home/(user)/Downloads/Chrome_test"}
};
chromeCapabilities.set('chromeOptions', chromeOptions);
var driver = new webdriver.Builder()
  .withCapabilities(chromeCapabilities)
  .build();
```

Comment: In window, controlled by webdriver, i went to settings and location to save was default: /home/elena/'Загрузки'
This is my changed path:
'prefs': {"download.default_directory":"/home/elena/'Загрузки'/Chrome_test"}